# Error appears while configuring Hue on my ubuntu 12.04

Tags: maven, ubuntu-12.04, hue

The error message appears after Download this:
http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/mina/build/2.0.0-M2/build-2.0.0-M2.pom

```
Downloaded: http ://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/mina/build/2.0.0-M2/build-2.0.0-M2.pom (16 KB at 35.5 KB/sec)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1:02.378s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Jan 15 13:21:14 SGT 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/120M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project hue-plugins: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.cloudera.hue:hue-plugins:jar:3.7.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies for [org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client:jar:2.5.0-mr1-cdh5.4.0-SNAPSHOT (compile), org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1 (compile), org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.6.1 (compile), commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.0.4 (compile), commons-logging:commons-logging-api:jar:1.0.4 (compile), org.apache.thrift:libthrift:jar:0.9.0 (compile), junit:junit:jar:4.8.1 (test), org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-test:jar:2.5.0-mr1-cdh5.4.0-SNAPSHOT (test)]: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client:jar:2.5.0-mr1-cdh5.4.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client:pom:2.5.0-mr1-cdh5.4.0-SNAPSHOT from/to cloudera.snapshots.repo (https://repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/snapshots): Connection to https://repository.cloudera.com refused: Connection refused -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] 
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException 
make[2]: *** [/home/paragonhao/hue/desktop/libs/hadoop/java-lib/hue-plugins-3.7.0-SNAPSHOT.jar] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/paragonhao/hue/desktop/libs/hadoop'
make[1]: *** [.recursive-env-install/libs/hadoop] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/paragonhao/hue/desktop'
make: *** [desktop] Error 2
```

Thank you!

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant but in the URL of the cloudera repo there is a space between `https` and `://` (`https ://repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/snapshots`). Could that be an issue? Is there a space in your configuration of this repo (either in your pom.xml or settings.xml)?

Comment: I added that purposely because I can only have two Hyperlinks in one post. But thank you anyway

Comment: Could you bump this file like https://github.com/cloudera/hue/commit/e63df3871bc1dcb5c0b63f74318f643a4547f06a ? It was fixed in 3.7.1, we should update the tarball release.

Comment: Done! http://gethue.com/hue-3-7-with-sentry-app-and-new-search-widgets-are-out/